# capacitor symbols

Tags: capacitor

trying to replace a component on a smoke machine.  Tried all sources to identify what looks like a capacitor.  However I do not understand the symbol.  Could anyone advise.  It actually sits across the 110v supply to a transformer.[image]

Comment: Can you show us a photo of the other side of the circuit board where the component went - including where the traces go to? Ideally, you would show us a circuit diagram for it.

Comment: It's a metal oxide varistor (MOV) used  to absorb spikes (and eventually die in the process). Pick one rated for your mains voltage and of the same physical diameter and you should be fine.

Comment: Sorry Andrew.... still learning.  Mr Anonymous has answered it's a Varistor but look like a cap...  Thank you for responding

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a line transient "smoked" the MOV and should have blown the fuse too.

Here is a [**list**](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/circuit-protection/tvs-varistors-movs/655423?k=&pkeyword=&FV=1c0003%2C1c80004%2C1c80006%2C1c80044%2C1c80045%2C1c800c5%2Cfff4000a%2Cfff8003f%2C1cc0007%2C1cc0028%2C1cc006f&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500) of potential replacements.

Comment: Tony, Thank you for your signpost to replacement... And yes the fuse went as well... Brilliant service... Brilliant site... Thank you so much for your advice

Comment: I work for peanuts in retirement, this is simple stuff

Comment: As you know... Knowledge is priceless and valuable to those still green.  Being new how does one add a vote for you and the others who have answered?

Comment: once you have accumulated enough points

Comment: Thanks I will also read the arrival brief I have just received  :  )

Answer (score 2):

The device is a varistor: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varistor and here (as example and explanation, look at device Z1 on the diagram) http://www.pavouk.org/hw/en_atxps.html